# Duvida sobre entidade estrutura de join typeorm

Tags: entidade-relacionamento, entidade

Bom dia, estou com uma dúvida, eu montei alguns relacionamentos com o typeorm, onde na coluna de Join, na tabela recebe um id_equipamento, mas no typeorm eu seto o tipo para a entidade que ele referencia, recebendo um equipamento completo. É possível eu buscar por um id que seria a forma original? Não sei se fiz a estrutura correta também, segue um código de exemplo.

Entidade Medida:

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Equipamento } from './equipamento.entity';
import { InfoMedida } from './infoMedida.entity';

@Entity('sig_medida')
export class Medida {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => InfoMedida, (infoMedida) => infoMedida.undMedidas)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_und_medida' })
  undMedida: InfoMedida;

  @ManyToOne(() => InfoMedida, (infoMedida) => infoMedida.tipoMedidas)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_tipo_medida' })
  tipoMedida: InfoMedida;

  @ManyToOne(() => Equipamento, (equipamento) => equipamento.medidas)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_equipamento' })
  equipamento: Equipamento;

  @Column({ type: 'numeric' })
  medida: number;
}
```

Entidade Equipamento:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Classe } from './classe.entity';
import { EstruturaEquipamento } from './equipamento-estrutura.entity';
import { Fabrica } from './fabrica.entity';
import { Familia } from './familia.entity';
import { Marca } from './marca.entity';
import { Medida } from './medida.entity';
import { Modelo } from './modelo.entity';
import { Setor } from './setor.entity';
import { Solicitacao } from './solicitacao.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'sig_equipamento' })
export class Equipamento {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Classe, (classe) => classe.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_classe' })
  classe: Classe;

  @ManyToOne(() => Marca, (marca) => marca.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_marca' })
  marca: Marca;

  @ManyToOne(() => Modelo, (modelo) => modelo.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_modelo' })
  modelo: Modelo;

  @ManyToOne(() => Familia, (familia) => familia.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_familia' })
  familia: Familia;

  @ManyToOne(() => Fabrica, (fabrica) => fabrica.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_fabrica' })
  fabrica: Fabrica;

  @ManyToOne(() => Setor, (setor) => setor.equipamentos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id_setor' })
  setor: Setor;

  @Column({ name: 'id_sankhya', type: 'int' })
  idSankhya: number;

  @Column({ name: 'cod_cent_cust', type: 'int' })
  codCentroCusto: number;

  @Column()
  ativo: boolean;

  @Column()
  nome: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  tag: string;

  @Column({ name: 'qtd_estoque', type: 'int' })
  qtdEstoque: number;

  @Column({ name: 'n_serie', type: 'int' })
  nSerie: number;

  @Column({ name: 'ano_fabricacao', type: 'int' })
  anoFabricacao: number;

  @Column({ name: 'data_instalacao', type: 'date' })
  dataInstalacao: Date;

  @Column({ name: 'data_compra', type: 'date' })
  dataCompra: Date;

  @Column()
  descricao: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => EstruturaEquipamento,
    (estruturas) => estruturas.equipamentoPai,
  )
  estruturasPai: EstruturaEquipamento[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => EstruturaEquipamento,
    (estruturas) => estruturas.equipamentoFilho,
  )
  estruturasFilho: EstruturaEquipamento[];

  @OneToMany(() => Solicitacao, (solicitacoes) => solicitacoes.componente)
  solicitacoesComponentes: Solicitacao[];

  @OneToMany(() => Solicitacao, (solicitacoes) => solicitacoes.maquina)
  solicitacoesMaquinas: Solicitacao[];

  @OneToMany(() => Medida, (medidas) => medidas.equipamento)
  medidas: Medida[];
}
```

[Tabela Medida](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38bf7.png)

[tabela Equipamento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrvG3.png)

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso a solução foi utilizar no find usar as seguintes opções:

```
this.estruturaRepository.find(
      {
        where: {
          equipamentoPai: {
            id: id,
          },
        },
        relations: ['equipamentoFilho'],
      },
    );
```

Dessa forma ele vai acessar a estrutura do pai no where pegando o id de dentro dele.